# Why did Munkres treat the case $A = \emptyset$ separately? ("Topology 2nd Edition" by James R. Munkres.)

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, logic

I am reading "Topology 2nd Edition" by James R. Munkres.

Munkres wrote:

> "$A$ is finite if it is empty or if there is a bijection $$f : A \to \{1,\dots,n\}$$ for some positive integer $n$.".

Munkres didn't write:

> "$A$ is finite if there is a bijection $$f : A \to S_n := \{x \in \mathbb{Z}_{+} \mid x < n\}$$ for some positive integer $n$.".

Note that $S_1 = \emptyset$ and there is a bijection $$f : A \to S_1 = \emptyset$$ if and only if $A = \emptyset$.

Why?

[image]

Comment: At least based on what I'm seeing, there's no inherently important difference. But I guess that $\{1,\cdots,n\}$ has cardinality $n$ makes more intuitive sense to write here than using $S_n$ which has cardinality $n-1$. (Even moreso since $S_n = \{1,\cdots,n-1\}$; why bother with the slight disparity here?)

Comment: Just to avoid the "weird" bijection $\varnothing\to\varnothing$ I guess. It might spare time for students who are not quite familiar with that sort of things. "Let them learn that if they study set-theory. Now it is time for topology..." he might have thought.

Comment: Some students moan when one writes let $A=\{1,\ldots,n\}$ and then one considera the case where $n=0$ (but $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ always has $1$ in it), or complain when one sets $n=1$ in $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ etc.

Comment: @AnginaSeng  Setting n = 0 in that expression deserves a moan and perhaps also a groan.  If you want to set n = 0, use the accurate well formed set built version instead of a not well formed shortcut notation.

Comment: Eevee Trainer, drhab, Angina Seng, William Elliot, Thank you very much for your comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only Munkres can answer your question "why"? Anyway, his definition is correct and your definition is correct, so it is a matter of taste which you prefer.

But do you really believe that your definition is more transparent? You first define the set $S_n$ and then observe that it is empty if for $n = 1$. This step is nothing else than *thinking about* the two cases $n >1$ and $n = 1$. And, by the way, it would be easier to define $S_n = \{ x \in \mathbb Z \mid 1 \le x \le n\}$. Then $S_0 = \emptyset$ and $S_n = \{1,\ldots,n \}$ for $n \ge 1$. Using $S_n$ is close to what Munkres does: You have the empty set and the nonempty sets $\{1,\ldots,n \}$ for positive integers $n$. These are the prototypes of finite sets.

Comment: { x positive integer  :  x <= n } has exactly n >= 0 elements without the nuisance of two cases.

Comment: @WilliamElliot You are of course right, your definition is exactly the same as my definition of $S_n$. The two cases "empty / nonempty" exist even we do not explicitly talk about them. Munkres talks about it, and that is the difference.

Comment: @PaulFrost: Given the importance that he attaches to clear exposition, it’s a fairly safe bet that Munkres thought that his version was clearer. It may even be clearer for a majority of students, but I dislike it: it’s unnecessarily complicated and makes an artificial distinction between $0$ and the other finite cardinals. I much prefer to say that a set is finite iff there is a bijection between it and $\{k\in\Bbb N:k<n\}$ for some $n\in\Bbb N$ (where $\Bbb N$ includes $0$).

Comment: @BrianM.Scott From an "advanced" perspective you are absolutely right. For $n \ge 0$ we can define $S_n = \{ x \in \mathbb Z \mid 1 \le x \le n\}$. Then $A$ is finite iff there is bijection $A \to S_n$ for some $n$. In that case $A$ has cardinality $n$. But if you explain this to beginners, you would certainly say that $S_n$ is the prototype of a set with $n$ elements and probably *say* explicitly that $S_0$ is the empty set and $S_n = \{1,\ldots,n\}$ for $n \ge 1$. This is what Munkres has done in written form. Yes, there is no need to do so, but perhaps it is didactically appropriate.

Comment: @PaulFrost: I **have** explained it to beginners, and I never start the natural numbers at $1$ (though in some contexts we may spend a bit of time on $0$-based versus $1$-based indexing), so no, I would not (and did not, before I retired) use the set $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ as the prototype of a set with $n$ elements. Depending on the course, I would either take it for granted that everyone had an informal understanding of what it means for a set to have cardinality $n$ for natural numbers $n$ or do it right.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I agree that we can start the natural numbers at $0$ and that the definition $S'_n = \{ k \in \mathbb N \mid k < n\}$ produces a set of cardinality $n$. My point is that beginners would probably regard $n = 0$ as a separate case (and  perhaps ask the teacher). But maybe I am wrong.

Comment: @PaulFrost: Some do.  That’s okay, since it allows me to reinforce the notion that $0$ is not special when it’s actually necessary to do so, but I prefer adopting that view from the outset and treating it as much as possible as a matter of course. It’s not a really big deal, but it is a choice that I would always make the same way, just as I would never start a topology course with metric spaces or an abstract algebra course with rings, though in both cases I understand the reasons of those who do.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, Paul Frost. Thank you very much for your comment, Brian M. Scott.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment, William Elliot.